# method is not invoked

Tags: java, android

method is not invoked

```
//view flipper code 
......................................
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;
private float initialX;
private Context mContext;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mContext = this;
    mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);

    //play and stop button for image slideshow(working fine)

    findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
            mViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000);
            mViewFlipper.startFlipping();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mViewFlipper.stopFlipping();

        }
    });

}
//The below method is not getting invoked

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = touchevent.getX();
            System.out.println(initialX); 
            //not displaying value in android 
            monitor
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float finalX = touchevent.getX();
            System.out.println(finalX);
            //not displaying value in android monitor
            if (initialX > finalX) {
                if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                 //image flipper has 3 images
                    break;
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
            } else {
                if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 2)
                    break;
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: please show your log

Comment: 07-25 19:06:10.571 9714-9714/com.example.cortana.shopv3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
07-25 19:06:10.699 9714-9714/com.example.cortana.shopv3 D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8bb8d98): name, size, mSize = 12, 16384, 15028224

Comment: on swipe left and right, x value is not printed on monitor

Comment: No log on swipe but.Slide show is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Well, It seems you're trying to perform some action on touching some view. For that you should override `OnTouchListener` of the view for which you want to receive touch event. It can be done as follows:

```
findViewById(R.id.your_view_id).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = touchevent.getX();
                    System.out.println(initialX);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    float finalX = touchevent.getX();
                    System.out.println(finalX);
                    if (initialX > finalX) {
                        if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                            //image flipper has 3 images
                            break;
                        mViewFlipper.showNext();
                    } else {
                        if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 2)
                            break;
                        mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i need to change the image on swipe on view flipper

Comment: Why don't you use ViewPager for that? Check this link out if you want to do something like that.
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 1):

onTouchEvent is only for Views. Activities are not views themselves. Instead, you need to set an onTouchListener.

Comment: I've done a test program for image flipper with same code and worked fine.But in this program method is not getting invoked

Comment: **onTouchEvent isn't a method in Activities.**. OnTouchEvent is in Views. If you had a view, the code would be correct. Otherwise, you need an onTouchListener